# upgrade of airflow 1.9 to airflow 1.10.2: task_log_reader error

Tags: airflow

I encountered with "task_log_reader" error after upgrade airflow from 1.9 version to 1.10.2 version.

The error is: "airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: Configured task_log_reader 'task' was not a handler of the 'airflow.task' logger"

I changed airflow.cfg as in https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.2/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg :

```
task_log_reader = task
log_filename_template = {{{{ ti.dag_id }}}}/{{{{ ti.task_id }}}}/{{{{ ts }}}}/{{{{ try_number }}}}.log
log_processor_filename_template = {{{{ filename }}}}.log
```

- etc

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you able to solve this problem? If yes, what is the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant; I had a similar issue but with a different error message.

This is what the correct configuration file should look like:

```
log_filename_template = {{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}/{{ try_number }}.log
log_processor_filename_template = {{ filename }}.log
```